# does write mode create a new file if not existing?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write to a file that does not already exist using a file context manager.

```
a=open ('C:/c.txt' , 'w')
```

The above does not succeed. How would I create a file for writing if it does already exist?

Comment: no repro, works just fine for me

Comment: Please add to your question: what version of Python, what platform you are running on (Windows?) and the exact error message.

Comment: The "w" mode should automatically create the file if it doesn't exist - could you please edit your question to include the specific commands/code you're running and the error message and traceback that results? Thanks.

Comment: @all: Sorry the error was overcomed..it was permissions problem in windows vista as most you suggested...thnq

Comment: You could try using `w+`

Answer (score 30):

Yes, `'w'` is specified as creating a new file -- as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) put it,

> 'w' for writing (truncating the file
>   if it already exists),

(clearly inferring it's allowed to not already exist).  Please show the exact traceback, not just your own summary of it, as details matters -- e.g. if the actual path you're using is different, what's missing might be the drive, or some intermediate directory; or there might be permission problems.

Comment: Note that it will NOT create directories if those don't exist though.

Answer (score 4):

[Edited to reflect that the problem is likely not forward vs. back slash]

If I understood correctly, you want the file to be automatically created for you, right?

open in write mode does create the file for you. It would be more clear if you told us the exact error you're getting. It might be something like you not having permission to write in C:.

I had previously suggested that it might be because of the forward slash, and indicated that the OP could try:

```
a = open(r'C:\c.txt', 'w')
```

Note the *r* before the file path, indicating *raw mode* (that is, the backslash won't be interpreted as special).

However, as Brian Neal pointed out (as well as others, commenting elsewhere), that's likely not the reason for the error. I'm keeping it here simply for historical purposes.

Comment: It's not the forward slash. His code snippet works fine for me on Windows.

Comment: This occurred to me a bit later. I'm still waiting for the OP to give us the error, but I'll edit my answer in the meantime. Thanks :)

Comment: I had a problem with the forward slash! Thanks, nobody said anything about this.

Answer (score 3):

You most probably are trying to write to a directory that doesn't exist or one that you don't have permission writing to.

If you want to write to `C:\foo\bar\foobar.txt` then make sure that you've got a `C:\foo\bar\` that exists (and in case permissions work on Windows, make sure you've got the permission to write there).

Now when you open the file in write mode, a file should be created.

Comment: I bet this is a permissions problem. The default for Vista and Windows 7 is not to allow ordinary users to write files in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to be warned when the file doesn't exist, then you need to explicitly check for that.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python)